# Can 2 coverages generate the same Grothendieck Topology if the category is large?

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory

I am currently analyzing a category which is not small, but locally small. I have seen that any coverage on any small category $\mathcal{C}$ generates a unique Grothendieck Topology on $\mathcal{C}$ in the book Sketches of an Elephant. Is this however also the case for locally small categories, or maybe essentially small categories? If it is not, a counterexample would be really helpful.
(Edit): Comments explain that this question is wrong.

Comment: Are your covering families small?

Comment: I guess there's really two questions there: Are your covering families themselves small, and are the collections of covering families generated by small subcollections in the appropriate sense?

Comment: I think the question is confused.  It's already the case for small categories that two different coverages can generate the same Grothendieck topology.  "Any coverage generates a unique Grothendieck topology" means there is a function from coverages to topologies, but the function is not injective.

Comment: @JamesHanson Yes, the covering families are small, should I maybe specify what category I am specifically working in?

Comment: @MikeShulman Then I am very confused. Could you maybe give an example of two coverages generating the same topology? (Or refer to one)

Comment: @wouterfransen If Mike's point doesn't already answer the question, it would probably be useful to actually specify the category.

Comment: A topology is a particular kind of coverage, which generates itself.  So any coverage that is not itself a topology provides an example: itself and the topology that it generates are two distinct coverages that generate the same topology.

Comment: Okay that explains alot, a bit stupid on my side to overlook that thanks.